# Rotary Encoder on LoLin NodeMcu increases value when rotating right/left

Tags: interrupt, rotary-encoder, nodemcu

I have a test program running on my LoLin NodeMcu board, with a Rotary Encoder connected.

I use `Task.h` and `RotaryEncoderTask.h` from this library: https://github.com/Makuna/Task (though my issue is the same when I use example code from here: https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-040_Rotary_encoder_module

Link to `RotaryEncoderTask.h`: https://github.com/Makuna/Task/blob/master/examples/RotaryEncoder/RotaryEncoderTask.h

**The problem**

When I turn the knob right and left a bit quickly, multiple successive times, the current value of the rotary encoder increases, rather than staying at the same value.

I've read something about `interrupts`, and I believe the issue is there somewhere, but I am not able to comprehend it enough to set it into practice.

Here is the code I am running:

```cpp
 /*
 * Pin mappings on LoLin:
 * 
 * static const uint8_t D0   = 16;
 * static const uint8_t D1   = 5;
 * static const uint8_t D2   = 4;
 * static const uint8_t D3   = 0;
 * static const uint8_t D4   = 2;
 * static const uint8_t D5   = 14;
 * static const uint8_t D6   = 12;
 * static const uint8_t D7   = 13;
 * static const uint8_t D8   = 15;
 * static const uint8_t D9   = 3;
 * static const uint8_t D10  = 1;
*/
// RotaryEncoder
// This demonstrates the use of the custom Task object feature of Task library
// It will instance one custom RotaryEncoderTask to monitor three pins that a 
// rotary encoder is connected to and make call backs when they change state;
// the press button will have debouce and auto repeat support;
// the rotary will tell direction and keep track of "clicks" rotated
// This requires a standard rotary encoder be attached to the defined pins,
//
// Usefull information will be sent to the serial monitor 
//
// make sure that you connect your rotary encoder correctly, include gnd and Vcc (+)

#include <Arduino.h>

// nothing special about these pins, just make sure they don't collide with
// other active features
#define ClockPin 5  // labeled either as CLK or as A
#define DataPin 4   // labeled either as DT or as B
#define ButtonPin 0 // labeled as SW

// include libraries
#include <Task.h>

// include sub files
#include "RotaryEncoderTask.h" // this implements the rotary encoder task

TaskManager taskManager;

// foreward delcare functions passed to task constructors now required
void HandleButtonChanged(EncoderButtonState state);
void HandleRotationChanged(int8_t rotationDelta);


RotaryEncoderTask RotaryTask(HandleRotationChanged,
    HandleButtonChanged,
    ClockPin,
    DataPin,
    ButtonPin);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(57600);
    while (!Serial); // wait for serial monitor to connect


    taskManager.StartTask(&RotaryTask);

    Serial.println("Running...");
}

void loop()
{
    taskManager.Loop();
}

void HandleButtonChanged(EncoderButtonState state)
{
    if (state == EncoderButtonState_Pressed)
    {
        Serial.println("Pressed - ");
    }
    else if (state == EncoderButtonState_Released)
    {
        Serial.println("Released - ");
    } 
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Auto-repeat - ");
    }
}

void HandleRotationChanged(int8_t rotationDelta)
{
    if (rotationDelta > 0)
    {
        Serial.print("clockwise = ");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.print("counter-clockwise = ");
    }

    Serial.println(RotaryTask.RotationValue());
}
```

Here is the result, where you see the current value increasing:

```cpp
counter-clockwise = -1
counter-clockwise = -2
counter-clockwise = -3
counter-clockwise = -4
counter-clockwise = -5
counter-clockwise = -6
counter-clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
counter-clockwise = -9
clockwise = -8
clockwise = -7
clockwise = -6
clockwise = -5
clockwise = -4
clockwise = -3
clockwise = -2
clockwise = -1
clockwise = 0
counter-clockwise = -1
counter-clockwise = -2
counter-clockwise = -3
counter-clockwise = -4
counter-clockwise = -5
counter-clockwise = -6
counter-clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
counter-clockwise = -9
counter-clockwise = -10
counter-clockwise = -11
clockwise = -10
clockwise = -9
clockwise = -8
clockwise = -7
clockwise = -6
counter-clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
counter-clockwise = -9
counter-clockwise = -10
clockwise = -9
clockwise = -8
clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
clockwise = -7
clockwise = -6
clockwise = -5
counter-clockwise = -6
counter-clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
counter-clockwise = -9
clockwise = -8
clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
clockwise = -7
counter-clockwise = -8
counter-clockwise = -9
counter-clockwise = -10
counter-clockwise = -11
clockwise = -10
counter-clockwise = -11
clockwise = -10
counter-clockwise = -11
clockwise = -10
counter-clockwise = -11
counter-clockwise = -12
counter-clockwise = -13
counter-clockwise = -14
counter-clockwise = -15
counter-clockwise = -16
counter-clockwise = -17
counter-clockwise = -18
clockwise = -17
clockwise = -16
counter-clockwise = -17
counter-clockwise = -18
counter-clockwise = -19
counter-clockwise = -20
counter-clockwise = -21
counter-clockwise = -22
counter-clockwise = -23
counter-clockwise = -24
counter-clockwise = -25
clockwise = -24
clockwise = -23
counter-clockwise = -24
counter-clockwise = -25
clockwise = -24
counter-clockwise = -25
counter-clockwise = -26
clockwise = -25
counter-clockwise = -26
clockwise = -25
counter-clockwise = -26
counter-clockwise = -27
counter-clockwise = -28
counter-clockwise = -29
clockwise = -28
counter-clockwise = -29
counter-clockwise = -30
counter-clockwise = -31
counter-clockwise = -32
clockwise = -31
clockwise = -30
counter-clockwise = -31
counter-clockwise = -32
counter-clockwise = -33
counter-clockwise = -34
clockwise = -33
counter-clockwise = -34
counter-clockwise = -35
counter-clockwise = -36
counter-clockwise = -37
counter-clockwise = -38
clockwise = -37
clockwise = -36
clockwise = -35
counter-clockwise = -36
clockwise = -35
counter-clockwise = -36
counter-clockwise = -37
clockwise = -36
clockwise = -35
clockwise = -34
clockwise = -33
clockwise = -32
counter-clockwise = -33
counter-clockwise = -34
clockwise = -33
```

Comment: I guess that you should not use serial print in the callbacks. Especially if they are called by the ISR.

Comment: Okay? Why and what can I use instead? Thanks :-)

Comment: Move the print from the callbacks to the loop function. Print periodically or on value change.

Comment: are your sure the library uses interrupts or pin change interrupts for the encoder pins? because the behavior you explained is the expected if checking encoder pins at regular intervals rather than using pin change interrupts.

Comment: I don't know enough about interrupts to answer, really. The `RotaryEncoderTask.h` can be found here: https://github.com/Makuna/Task/blob/master/examples/RotaryEncoder/RotaryEncoderTask.h

Comment: From that code '
        Task(MsToTaskTime(5)), // check every five millisecond, 1-10 ms should be ok' so it checks every 5ms, I think there is a chance for it to mis one.

Comment: Write some code where you print the encoder value in the loop. And in your interrupts you only change this value. Keep the interrupt as short as possible, you don't have to print there as your loop will already do so.

Comment: Also, check the datasheet of this unit, I believe it has two pins. When both are open or both closed, you know the direction when the next state is one open and one closed.